# How to perform Infinite scrolling in android using Volley request

Tags: android, android-listview, android-volley, infinite-scroll

I have a listview in an activity which renders a list values obtained from the JSON response.I am successfully able to display list view the code is as shown below

```
listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        adapter = new CustomListAdapter(this, productList);
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);



        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        // Showing progress dialog before making http request
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        pDialog.show();

        GsonRequest<Product[]> getPersons =
                new GsonRequest<Product[]>(Request.Method.GET,url, Product[].class,

                        requestSuccessListener(), requestErrorListener());

        AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(getPersons);
```

Now when user scrolls to the end of the list view i want to load more details by another REST call. Please help me on how to perform this operation such that the previous data in the adapter should not be changed and present should be appended below it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

for endless scrolling refer here https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Endless-Scrolling-with-AdapterViews-and-RecyclerView  .. for each   `customLoadMoreDataFromApi(page)` call load data to the adapter and call notify data set changed..

Comment: Hey thanks a lot, It worked like a charm, i know its another question but can you tell me on how to display a loading image kind of thing at the bottom of screen when loading data?

Comment: dead article in link